# Not drawing sublayers in a class that inheritates from UIImageView from the ViewController class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, viewcontroller

First of all, I apologize, because I am starting iOS development.

I have a "Lienzo" class, that inheritates from UIImageView to perform some graphic tasks in response to a touch event:

```
 @interface Lienzo : UIImageView

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];
    int count = [allTouches count];
    if (count > 0){
       touch1 = [[allTouches objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self];
       [self dibujaCirculo:1 ];
    }
   }

-(void)dibujaCirculo:(int)instrumento {

    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [circleLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [self bounds].size.width,
                                  [self bounds].size.height)];

     [circleLayer setPosition:CGPointMake([self bounds].size.width/2.0f,
                                     [self bounds].size.height/2.0f)];
     UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
                      CGRectMake(50.0,50.0,60.0*instrumento,60.0*instrumento)];

    [circleLayer setPath:[path CGPath]];
    [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]];
    [[self layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];
  }
```

The code works fine when I click on the image on the screen, and shows the circle on screen.

But I want to use an object of Lienzo also on the ViewController. I have a property on the ViewController to also draw on the same image.

```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet Lienzo *test;
```

I synthesize and allocate it on screen, but when I try to draw inside a method, it does not shows anything on the screen.

```
[_test dibujaCirculo:3];
```

I have seen that I don't have access from ViewController to the bounds values of the "Lienzo" class, so I know that I am doing something wrong. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Is `test` connected to a view in a XIB / Storyboard or manually created and added to the view hierarchy?

Comment: Lienzo was changed manually to inheritate from UIImageView and after that, test was connected manually from Storyboard. If I try to define "test" as a global variable on ViewController, the behaviour is the same